# Can "Exclude from View" be kept disabled during an append? Can it be done with Python?

Tags: python, outliner, viewlayers

This is a minor thing, but I was curious if this was possible.
I have generated a character rig that looks like this in the outliner. Notice the wgt folder is "disabled" and its contents are not visible (checkbox to the left of the eye is disabled)

[image: Before appending.]

However, when I append this character by just appending the "Character" collection, the wgt folder comes fully open. (checkbox enabled)

[image]

Now, pressing the checkbox is no issue post-append, but I was curious to know if there was a way to prevent this from the character .blend file so that it doesn't open when it's appended, and if it can be done with Python.

Thus far, I have this code that does a good job of excluding it on its own .blend file during the character rig generationg, but it doesn't prevent it from opening on append.

```
def recurLayerCollection(layerColl):
    found = None
    if (layerColl.name == "wgt"):
        return layerColl
    for layer in layerColl.children:
        found = recurLayerCollection(layer)
        if found:
            return found
layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection
layerColl = recurLayerCollection(layer_collection)
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = layerColl

layerColl.exclude = True
```

If it can't be done, no issue - but I'm curious to know if there's a way to do it solely for the sake of convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to add your own custom logic when appending with a python script, because the exclude state is not stored on the collection but on the view layer (as illustrated by your code snippet). If you don't want to go that far you can try something else.

What you can do is disable the collection with the monitor icon instead.

First enable the monitor icon restriction toggle in the outliner settings.

[image]

Then disable the collection in the outliner :

[image]

You might want to also disable it from rendering otherwise its elements will show up in your renders.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. Is there a way to make it so a python script (a text block) gets automatically ran when there's an append that includes that text block?